# How to draw the different butyl cations?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

On the image [image], can someone help me how to draw the different butyl cations? I'm confused as to where to place the positive charge on the different butyl cations. Going from left to right, the compounds are: isobutyl cation, n-butyl cation, and sec-butyl cation. Thank you so much!

Comment: What do you mean where to draw the charge?? The diagrams clearly show where (on which carbon) the +ve charge is.

Comment: @ShoubhikRMaiti, yes, but this is already the answer. The question asked me to draw the different butyl cations. How do I know where to place the + charge?

Comment: Oh I see, the cations are named in the same way as the side chains are named in organic compounds (alkyl group names). I will try to add an answer soon.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments, the carbocations are named in the same vein as the alkyl functional group/side chains are named. To some extent, you have to learn which structure the names correspond to. Look at [Alkyl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkyl) at wikipedia for the names of some alkyl groups.

For example:

[image: isopropyl]

This is the isopropyl group. When drawing the isopropyl cation, you will draw the positive charge at the carbon where the missing bond is (bond and then wavy line)

This is the isopropyl carbocation:

[image: isopropyl cation]